# How do I reset the scale?

Tags: javascript, scale, p5.js

The full code is:

```
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 10;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 20;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
    frameRate(50)
    createCanvas(600, 450);
    playerX = width/2
    playerY = height/2;
}

function draw() {
  
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    scale(10/playerSize)
    translate(-playerX, -playerY);
  
    playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10


    Newcelltimer++;

    background(220);

    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY > 0 - width) {
        playerY -= playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX < 2 * width) {
        playerX += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY < 2 * width) {
        playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX > 0 - width) {
        playerX -= playerSpeed;
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 30 == 0) {
        cell.push(ceil(random(0 - width, 2 * width)),
            ceil(random(0 - height, 2 * height)))

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {

        fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
        circle(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], 7)
    }



    fill(255, 255, 0)
    circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
    fill(0)
    ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    fill(255, 255, 0)
    noStroke()
    arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    stroke(0)




    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
        let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
        if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
            playerSize += 7;
            cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
        }
    }


    if (playerSize >= 3 * width | playerSize >= 3 * height) {
        if (width > height) {
            playerSize = height;
        } else {
            playerSize = width;
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that the text isn't on the screen all the times, so when your size gets bigger, and your field of vision gets bigger, the text changes the position on its screen, it's supposed to always stay in the top left corner, but as you get bigger, it gets closer to the bottom right corner. The equation for the zoom will be changed probably into something exponential, so feel free to change that for the solution.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and [`pop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place text on the canvas in a fixed position place it before any calls to `translate` or `scale`. Scale and translate are reset after every call to `draw`. If you need to reset scale inside of draw you can save the current state with a call to [`push`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and then return to the original state with a call to [`pop`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop). See the second example below.

Here is an example based on your sketch:

```js
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 10;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 20;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
    frameRate(50)
    createCanvas(600, 450);
    playerX = width/2
    playerY = height/2;
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    text("This Text Stays Right Here", 20, 20);
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    scale(10/playerSize)
    translate(-playerX, -playerY);
  
    playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10

    Newcelltimer++;

    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY > 0 - width) {
        playerY -= playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX < 2 * width) {
        playerX += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY < 2 * width) {
        playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX > 0 - width) {
        playerX -= playerSpeed;
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 30 == 0) {
        cell.push(ceil(random(0 - width, 2 * width)),
            ceil(random(0 - height, 2 * height)))
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {

        fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
        circle(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], 7)
    }
    fill(255, 255, 0)
    circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
    fill(0)
    ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    fill(255, 255, 0)
    noStroke()
    arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    stroke(0)

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
        let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
        if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
            playerSize += 7;
            cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
        }
    }
    if (playerSize >= 3 * width | playerSize >= 3 * height) {
        if (width > height) {
            playerSize = height;
        } else {
            playerSize = width;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Example with `push` and `pop`
Notice that calls to `stroke` are not pushed and popped so the text uses the stroke color set above.

```js
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 10;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 20;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
    frameRate(50)
    createCanvas(600, 450);
    playerX = width/2
    playerY = height/2;
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    push();
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    scale(10/playerSize)
    translate(-playerX, -playerY);
  
    playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10

    Newcelltimer++;

    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY > 0 - width) {
        playerY -= playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX < 2 * width) {
        playerX += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY < 2 * width) {
        playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX > 0 - width) {
        playerX -= playerSpeed;
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 30 == 0) {
        cell.push(ceil(random(0 - width, 2 * width)),
            ceil(random(0 - height, 2 * height)))
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {

        fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
        circle(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], 7)
    }
    fill(255, 255, 0)
    circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
    fill(0)
    ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    fill(255, 255, 0)
    noStroke()
    arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    stroke(0)

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
        let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
        if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
            playerSize += 7;
            cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
        }
    }
    if (playerSize >= 3 * width | playerSize >= 3 * height) {
        if (width > height) {
            playerSize = height;
        } else {
            playerSize = width;
        }
    }
    pop();
    // notice that calls to stroke are not pushed and popped
    text("This Text Stays Right Here Because of Push and Pop", 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```